# AutoLogin sem firebase SWIFT3 IOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-3

Queria saber como faço para o programa guardar as informações do usuário e o mesmo nao precisar logar sempre que minimizar ou fechar o app sem a utilização de firebase.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode armazenar informações pelo **UserDefauls**

Pra usar, tu pega a instância do UserDefauls do aplicativo e realiza operações de get e set sobre essa instância, como por exemplo abaixo,

```
// pega a instância do UserDefaults do 
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard 

//Verifico se para a chave showedHowTo tem um valor verdadeiro, se tiver eu faço algo...
if defaults.bool(forKey: "showedHowTo") {
    //faz alguma ação que é necessária

} else {
    //faz alguma ação que é necessária

    //marca a chave showedHoTo como verdadeira, na próxima vez que eu pegar o valor para essa chave, estará indicando verdadeiro
    defaults.set(true, forKey: "showedHowTo")
}
```

Mais informações sobre tu pode ler direto da [documentação da Apple,](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults) que traz métodos para armazenar String, int, float e etc...

No seu caso, como são informações de credenciais do usuário, caso tenha alguma informação muito sensível que necessite de criptografia, recomendaria você salvar no KeyChain, tendo em vista que o UserDefauls não criptografa as informações.

Pra usar o KeyChain, recomendo a biblioteca [KeyChain-Swift](https://github.com/evgenyneu/keychain-swift) que contém Wrappers pra você utilizar e é bem semelhante ao UserDefauls.